# Broken dependencies after installing kernel 4.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 MATE

Tags: kernel, dependencies

After updating my MATE 16.04 Ubuntu to Kernelversion 4.6 I get this weird broken dependencies and nothing worked out so far. I can't boot to another Kernel, whenever I tried this, everything freezes.

```
uname -a 
Linux der-desktop 4.6.2-040602-generic #201606100516 SMP Fri Jun 10 09:18:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Dist-Upgrade:

```
der@der-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
[sudo] password for der: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/39,0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-040400-generic (4.4.0-040400.201601101930) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-040400-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-040400-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-040400-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf': No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-040400-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-040400-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic (4.4.0-34.53) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-040400-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
dkms: WARNING: Linux headers are missing, which may explain the above failures.
      please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic package to fix this.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf': No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic (4.4.0-36.55) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf': No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic (--configure):
 package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-4.4.0-36-generic:
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-36-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic (= 4.4.0-36.55); however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-4.4.0-36-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-sigNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                  ned-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-signed-image-4.4.0-36-generic; however:
  Package linux-signed-image-4.4.0-36-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 4.4.0.36.38); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-040400-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-36-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Apt-Cache:

```
 apt-cache policy linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
    linux-generic:
      Installed: (none)
      Candidate: 4.4.0.36.38
      Version table:
         4.4.0.36.38 500
            500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
         4.4.0.21.22 500
            500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
    linux-image-generic:
      Installed: (none)
      Candidate: 4.4.0.36.38
      Version table:
         4.4.0.36.38 500
            500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
         4.4.0.21.22 500
            500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
    linux-headers-generic:
      Installed: 4.4.0.36.38
      Candidate: 4.4.0.36.38
      Version table:
     *** 4.4.0.36.38 500
            500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         4.4.0.21.22 500
            500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Seems like something is missing, but I can't re-install anything... :(

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/kernel64bit/4.4.0-34.53/
cd ~/Downloads/kernel64bit/4.4.0-34.53/
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.4.0-34_4.4.0-34.53_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic_4.4.0-34.53_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic_4.4.0-34.53_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic_4.4.0-34.53_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt-get -f install 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-dejavu
sudo apt-get -f install
```